# django nonrel and the admin

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I am looking to use django non-rel on app engine for an upcoming project and would like to know.

Can I make use of the django admin, to create news articles in django non-rel or do I need to code my own admin?

Or will the standard django admin work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using django-nonrel, but not the admin.

I don't know the answer for sure, but I'm pretty sure it's possible, since other people have done it.

Django-nonrel works fine as long as you don't use any many-to-many relations.  If using many-to-many relations, I really don't know how well dbindexer works.  The admin may use many-to-many relations if you use permissions.  So depending on what contrib components you're using, you may run into problems.

Comment: Can you explain to me why in django-non-rel I can use models.Model or db.Models but both appear to save to the appengine data store? Surely models.Model should not save as this is SQL. What is the difference between models.Model and db.Models?

Comment: You should probably ask that as a separate question.  db.Models is the GAE native model API, that's what you need to use for a GAE app.  models.Model is a Django model API.  If you wanted to write a Django app, you'd use models.Model.  On pure Django, models.Model only works on SQL, and wouldn't work on GAE.  The django-nonrel project made models.Model work on GAE.  Now by using models.Model, you can plug in existing Django apps to your GAE Django project, or move your Django project off of GAE.

Comment: Wow thanks @dragonx thats really helped with my understanding. I have only ever used django once before for a small client and now a new client has been talking about django non-rel and I was not sure how the two compared. Your explanation has solved this for me.